# How to make a Hibernate Mapping file in IntelliJ 11 Ultimate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

How do you make a XML file that defines the DTD and the initial structure like you do with the Hibernate configuration file in IntelliJ 11 Ultimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's clearly described in the [manual from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/hibernate.html).

Comment: That seems to only provide an automatic way of making Java beans mapped in a Hibernate mapping file. What I asked for was just the standard template with the doctype the same way as with configuration